# Batch Script Values not changing?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script but for whatever reason once a value is set in my foor loop it persists and doesn't update. My values:'totalTime' and 'totalHours' in my for loop are always the same value of the first time 'converttime was called. I have verified that my 'converttime' function is accurately getting the right values but I am not sure how to get the values to change in my for loop.

My code looks like this:

```
@echo off

set duration=01:25:45

call :converttime %duration%

set /A duration=%totalHours%+%totalMins%

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=#" %%i IN (subtitle.txt) DO (
    call :converttime %%i
    set /A totalTime=%totalMins%+%totalhours%
    echo %totalTime%
)
endlocal
goto :eof

:converttime
set mytime=%1
set hour=%mytime:~0,2%
set minute=%mytime:~3,2%
set seconds=%mytime:~6,7%

if NOT "%minute%"=="" (
    SET /A totalMins=%minute%*60000
)

if NOT "%hour%"=="~0,2" (
    set /A totalhours=%hour%*3600000    
)
```

The output is:

4500000
4500000
4500000
4500000
4500000
4500000

When it should be something like:

2500000
3520000
1450000

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I just needed to use the 'setLocal' command. and surround my variables with ! instead of %

My completed code looks like this:

```
@echo off

set duration=01:25:45
call :converttime %duration%

set /A duration=%totalHours%+%totalMins%
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=#" %%i IN (subtitle.txt) DO (
    call :converttime %%i
    set /A totalTime=!totalMins!+!totalhours!
    echo !totalTime!
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:converttime
set mytime=%1
set hour=%mytime:~0,2%
set minute=%mytime:~3,2%
set seconds=%mytime:~6,7%

if NOT "%minute%"=="" (
    SET /A totalMins=%minute%*60000
)

if NOT "%hour%"=="~0,2" (
    set /A totalhours=%hour%*3600000    
)
```

Comment: This is called "delayed expansion".